# Internet connecting shows force close in jellybean android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I want to check internet connection on my phone so i can play audio.
to check internet connection i wrote code and it works fine on all android version except **jellybean Nexus 7 tablet**. it show force close on nexus 7.

Here is my code for checking.

```
private void MyCheckinternet() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            if(connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || 
                    connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                //we are connected to a network
                connected = true;


            }
            else
            {
                connected = false;

    }


    }
```

And this is **logcat error:**

```
09-18 16:20:33.098: E/AndroidRuntime(3224): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
09-18 16:20:33.098: E/AndroidRuntime(3224): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-18 16:20:33.098: E/AndroidRuntime(3224):at
com.android.twitter.Main.MyCheckinternet(Vmix_Main.java:115)
09-18 16:20:33.098:E/AndroidRuntime(3224):  at com.android.twitter.Main.access$0(Main.java:112)
09-18 16:20:33.098: E/AndroidRuntime(3224):     at
com.android.twitter.Main$3.onClick(Main.java:520)
09-18 16:20:33.098: E/AndroidRuntime(3224):     at
android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
09-18 16:20:33.098: E/AndroidRuntime(3224):     at
android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
09-18 16:20:33.098: E/AndroidRuntime(3224):     at
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
09-18 16:20:33.098: E/AndroidRuntime(3224):     at
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-18 16:20:33.098: E/AndroidRuntime(3224):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
```

Comment: do you have the correct permission?

Comment: Can you specify which permission?

Comment: Post Vmix_Main.java:115 and surrounding code.

Comment: i have provide <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
But still force close on jellybean but work on 4.1 emulator

Comment: line numbers would help. There's a null pointer exception in line 115. I suspect it's something like getNetworkinfo returns null, so getState() generates a null pointer exception.

Comment: Ohh ok so how can i handle this null pointer exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
connectivityManager
```

or

```
connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
```

is null

My bet is on the second one. test it for null before testing the state of it. (the networkInfo may be null if the mobile network is not activated)

Comment: i rewrite this and it works
try{
 
            ConnectivityManager conMan = (ConnectivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = conMan.getActiveNetworkInfo();
       
            if(networkInfo.isConnected()){
         
               connected = true;
            } 
            else {
                connected = false;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
          
        System.out.print(ex);
        }
 
    }